# line-height css with Firefox

Tags: css, less

I have a problem with the font icon in firefox please check the Image 
[image]

CSS:

```
[class^="icon-"]::before, [class*=" icon-"]::before {
    font-family: "untitled-font-1" !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-variant: normal !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

The top bar in the firefox and the bottom in the Chrome and here the Live Link

http://mohammadsamy.com/Nest/

Comment: Please include a minimal, yet complete, code reproduction in your question, rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: @TylerH , Done  thanks for the comment

Comment: @MohamedSamy I'm sorry but I don't see items of your screenshots. Can you create a simplified jsFiddle?

Comment: Looks like the relevant bits are commented out in the HTML...

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to answer for me if you also supplied the relevant html code in order to try and test this out, but have you considered a more browser/screen-agnostic measurement type such as `vh` or `em`? Example:

```
[class^="icon-"]::before, [class*=" icon-"]::before {
    line-height: 1vh;
}
```

If that still doesn't work, you can always play with their `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` attributes.

- [Margin-bottom MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom)
- [Padding-bottom MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom)